# External Hard Drive wont search

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I plug my USB 2.0, 1TB, into my computer usb port. When i open the expansion drive and try to search it won't pull up any of my files. It used to, though now it won't. I tried on another computer, and yes it searches. How can I fix this?

Comment: What operating system? What are you using to search?

Comment: Its windows 7 32bit i believe

Comment: Are you using windows built in search, a 3rd party tool, or just trying to view files through explorer? Does the correct drive letter and volume information appear when you plug it in?

Comment: I am using the windows built in. I open the F drive expansion drive folder and there i have multiple music folders for my dj service. In that folder the windows search i type in an artist/genre/song/title whichever it may be and it used to work. then one day at a show setting up realized it stopped working.

Comment: Issue has been fixed. I uninstalled the driver and then reinstalled it. and now it works properly

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure the relevant drivers are up to date please.

Worse case, re-install the driver (or the software you are using (if applicable).

Comment: Ill try to find and locate that drive thanks ill let ya know